# visual studio export template error 'invalid parameter'

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-templates

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Premium on a 64-bit window's 7 laptop.  I want to export a template but I get the following error when I click finish in the `export template` form:

```
Template export failed for the following reason: Invalid parameter  
Parameter name: index
```

To make it I start a project from an existing template (typescript nodejs; blank express application) and then change it up to how I need it.  I do delete some folders and create new ones. I also rename the startup file from `app.ts` to `server.ts`.  I can't find anything explaining this error, and http://msdn.microsoft.com doesn't have anything, as far as I could see.   If someone could share some insight into how this problem or how to properly export a template it would be appreciated!

Comment: Same issue in VS2013.  I created a new node.js console app and simply tried to export it as a template with same message.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem on VS2017. :(

Comment: Same issue in VS2019

Comment: Same issue in VS2019 as well, if someone could bounty this question that'd be nice...

Comment: same on VS 2022. Can't believe this has been around this long without an answer.